# calling ros::spin or ros::spinOnce from other function in QT

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am very new to ROS and I have just manged to integrate the ROS libraries into my QT IDE.

I am building a fairly complex application, however the ROS subscriber example I am attempting to implement fairly simple.

If I implement my code this way (per the examples), I get subscriber callbacks as expected:

```
void MainWindow::rtsp1Callback(const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    qDebug() << "rtsp1 Image has data";
}
```

With this initializer:

```
void MainWindow::on_ROSSubscribeButton_clicked()
{
    ros::init(m_argc, m_argv, "camera_check");
    ros::NodeHandle n1;
    ros::Subscriber sub1 = n1.subscribe("/rtsp_1/image_raw", 100, &MainWindow::rtsp1Callback, this);
    ros::spin();
}
```

But of course, this is an undesirable design, as `ros::spin();` then blocks the rest of my program.

So I execute a timer to call `ros::spinOnce();` on demand:

Callback unchanged:

```
void MainWindow::rtsp1Callback(const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    qDebug() << "rtsp1 Image has data";
}
```

Initializer with timer:

```
void MainWindow::on_ROSSubscribeButton_clicked()
{
    ros::init(m_argc, m_argv, "camera_check");
    ros::NodeHandle n1;
    ros::Subscriber sub1 = n1.subscribe("/rtsp_1/image_raw", 100, &MainWindow::rtsp1Callback, this);
    CameraCheckTimer.start(100);  //calls ros::spinOnce() every 1000ms;
}
```

And this spin call (on timer execution):

```
void MainWindow::checkCameras()
{
    ros::spinOnce();
    qDebug() << "Spin!";
}
```

However I do not get any callbacks.

I also tested calling ros::spin() - which was working in my initial example, by calling a singleShot timer.  When I do this, my program blocks as expected, however I do not get any callbacks.

This makes me suspect that ros::spin() and ros::spinOnce() are somehow getting an implicit pointer to the GlobalCallbackQueue from the ros::init() function.  Is this the case?

If so, what is the data type of ros::GlobalCallbackQueue  (so that I can pass a global pointer to it into my timer loop)?

Or, if you have an example of how to simply fix my problem, I will accept that as well!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328378/calling-ros::spin-or-ros::spinonce-from-other-function-in-qt/) by [riot](https://answers.ros.org/users/44048/riot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2019-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Initializer with timer:
>
> ```
> void MainWindow::on_ROSSubscribeButton_clicked()
> ```

```
{
    ros::init(m_argc, m_argv, "camera_check");
    ros::NodeHandle n1;
    ros::Subscriber sub1 = n1.subscribe("/rtsp_1/image_raw", 100, &MainWindow::rtsp1Callback, this);
    CameraCheckTimer.start(100);  //calls ros::spinOnce() every 1000ms;
}
```

> However I do not get any callbacks.

The problem here is scope: `sub1` goes out of scope as soon as `on_ROSSubscribeButton_clicked()` completes.

So the `Subscriber` gets destroyed, cancelling the subscription. Additionally, the `NodeHandle` also vanishes.

Caling `ros::spinOne()` at this point doesn't really do much any more, as there are no subscriptions.

Make sure to keep the `ros::Subscriber` around, and probably also the `ros::NodeHandle` (as a member variable fi). Things should start working.

> This makes me suspect that ros::spin() and ros::spinOnce() are somehow getting an implicit pointer to the GlobalCallbackQueue from the ros::init() function. Is this the case?
>
> If so, what is the data type of ros::GlobalCallbackQueue (so that I can pass a global pointer to it into my timer loop)?

I don't believe this has anything to do with your problem.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [riot](https://answers.ros.org/users/44048/riot/) on 2019-07-12**:
Thank you for your very concise answer!

I simply declared the handles as 'static' and they now persist outside of the creation function:

```
void MainWindow::on_ROSSubscribeButton_clicked()
{
    ros::init(m_argc, m_argv, "camera_check");
    static ros::NodeHandle n1;
    static ros::Subscriber sub1 = n1.subscribe("/rtsp_1/image_raw", 100, &MainWindow::rtsp1Callback, this);
    CameraCheckTimer.start(100);  //calls ros::spinOnce() every 1000ms;
}
```

I get the callbacks as expected.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-12**:
I wouldn't declare them `static`, but if you are ok with doing it that way, that would work.